# CacheManager.create() very slow

Tags: java, ehcache

I am running an application using ehcache on an arm (arm5, no floating point unit) based machine, tested using both jamvm and openjdk and with a compact flash based rootfs (which is quite slow on this device).

When I time CacheManager.create() this takes from 15 to 30 seconds. Even when I pass the default configuration as a parameter this still takes so long. The configuration disables all disk persistency, and checking for updates is disabled as well. Creating a new Cache is faster again.

Does anyone know what I can do to make the CacheManager faster or why it is so slow?

Regards,
Leen

Comment: I imagine the persistent store on your device isn't very fast and ehcache may not access it in the most light weight way possible for your device. It was written for systems with performant IO.

Comment: Hi,

this is the configuration I am using.

Configuration config = new Configuration();
CacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
defaultCacheConfiguration.setOverflowToDisk(false);
defaultCacheConfiguration.setDiskPersistent(false);
config.setDefaultCacheConfiguration(defaultCacheConfiguration);
config.setUpdateCheck(false);


CacheManager mgr =  new CacheManager(config);

Which should never touch the disk unless I am wrong. This piece of code takes between 180 and 250 milliseconds on my machine. On the target machine this becomes half a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the same problem just now.

Turned out CacheManager.start() calls InetAddress.getLocalhost().

Now, my box was named, say "box2137" (not localhost). I chose this name when installing RHEL.

Turns out it was not added to /etc/hosts as 127.0.0.1/::1! When calling InetAddress.getLocalhost(), Java tried to DNS resolve "box2137" which took 30 seconds.

Adding "box2137" to /etc/hosts solves the issue.